# How to download a document from CompaniesHouse API through Postman?

Tags: vba, api, postman

I have been trying, this from 2 days and still didn't find a solution.
I am using the below URL
http://document-api.companieshouse.gov.uk/document/{id}/content
by passing valid document ID, however i keep getting the below error in Postman

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error>
>     <Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
>     <Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization
> header should be specified</Message>
>     <ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
>     <ArgumentValue>Basic b0JLOGNVOFZJSl9VR2xMWVlXemFlNkxXTb25sbnBqN0hkbw==</ArgumentValue>
>     <RequestId>09BCC38D383B796C</RequestId>
>     <HostId>qf2WVYFkSatKWLwgBLpRw/vpieDrbl1CNfdZERWUVCA46K40df3YVeFpdEs+l7+gVKW1vh4k0cY=</HostId>
> </Error>
```

Headers I tried so far

```
Content-Type: Application/xml
Content-Type: Application/pdf
Accept: Application/pdf
```

not sure if I have to pass something in headers.
The other URL like https://api.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/{company Number}/filing-history
works fine, it returns a response so I don't think there is an issue with my API key

Error screenshot:
[image: Postman screen shot]

Comment: The content-type header on the example request is `application/json` https://developer.companieshouse.gov.uk/document/docs/document/id/fetchDocumentMeta.html - are you able to attach a screen shot of your Postman request?

Comment: Danny, i attached the screenshot to the original question

Comment: Have you tried the request through their documentation page? It’s telling you information about the Auth method that something isn’t quite right - recreate the token, create a new request in a different tab etc. I was looking at th other endpoint so the content-type isn’t needed.

Comment: When I try in their page, i get this error Failure while contacting API. Some possible causes are connection problems or cross-origin resource sharing protection. Please check javascript domains registered against APIKey / OAuth2 registration.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is with the API key being transferred twice to C house so I have tried this

Browse to the document metadata in one request and take an untitled request and hit the document API it will work